# Plot the evaluated results of NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to get a plot of dpdx vs x using the following code. But I am getting a blank window.

```
sol[x_] := Module[{a, b, t, Q0, alp, alpha, m, beta, k, F, h, sol},
   a = 0.5;
   b = 2.0;
   t = 0.0;
   Q0 = 1.0;
   alp = 0.5;
   alpha = 0.5;
   beta = 1.0;
   k = 0.5;
   m = 50;
   F = Q0*Exp[-alp*t];
   h = 1.0 - (a*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]);
   sol = NDSolve[{s''[y] == (m/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]], 
      p''''[y] - (1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*s'[y] == 0, s'[0] == 0, 
      s[h] == 1, p[0] == 0, p''[0] == 0, p[h] == F, p'[h] == 0}, {s, 
      p}, {y, 0, h}];
    dpdx = Evaluate[p'''[y] - (1/k)*p'[y] + (beta*m*m*s[y]) /. sol];
   {0, h, sol}];
Monitor[data = Flatten[Table[{0, h, funcs} = sol[x];
     Table[{x, y, Last@(dpdx /. funcs)}, {y, 0, h, .1}], {x, 0, 
      1, .1}], 1];, {x, dpdx}]
ListPlot[data]
```

Comment: `NDSolve` gives the error message "NDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable p " . Inserting the boundary values into the ode I get ` $\left\{s''(0)=100. \sinh (0.5 s(0)),p^{(4)}(0)+0.=0\right\}$

Comment: I have included the boundary conditions in the code.

Comment: Yes, I took these boundary conditions  to get the initial state `{s''[y] == (m/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]], 
   p''''[y] - (1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*s'[y] == 0} /. 
  y -> 0 /. {s'[0] -> 0, s[h] -> 1, p[0] -> 0, p''[0] -> 0, p[h] -> F,
   p'[h] -> 0}`

Comment: Did you get the desired plot?

Comment: No I didn't. Because `NDSolve` doesn't evaluate (see my first comment). Did you check the boundary conditions?

Comment: Try changing `NDSolve[..]` to `First@NDSolve[..]` and `{x, y, Last@(dpdx /. funcs)}` to `{x, dpdx /. funcs}`. `s = NDSolve[]` returns a set of solutions (just one solution) and `expr /. s` gives the corresponding set of answer (wrapped in `{..}`). For `ListPlot[data]`, you want elements of the form `{x1, dpdx1}`, not `{x, {dpdx1}}`. (A good thing to do when `ListPlot` does not work as expected is to examine the data to see if it's in the proper form.) I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaJqx.png

Answer (score 1):

**modified**

Here my approach (Mathematica v12.2) solving the problem with Shootingmethod `Method->"Shooting"`

```
sol[h_, F_] :=Block[{sol}, 
sol = NDSolve[{s''[y] == (m/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]],p''''[y] -(1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*s'[y] == 0
, s'[0] == 0,s[h] == 1, p[0] == 0, p''[0] == 0, p[h] == F, p'[h] == 0}, {s,p}, {y, 0, h}
, Method -> "Shooting"][[1]];
{h, y,   p'''[y] - (1/k)*p'[y] + (beta*m*m*s[y]) /. sol }
]
```

function `sol[h,F]` returns `{h, y,  dpdx[h,y] }`

```
Show[Table[
ParametricPlot3D[sol[h, 1], {y, 0.01 h ,  .99 h}, Evaluated -> True,PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> {0 } ]
,{h,Range[#, 1, #] &[.0125]}], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {0, 1000}, AxesLabel -> {"h", "y", "dpdx"}]
```

[image]

`dpdx[h,y]`, see second ode, must be constant for given h.
It is obvious to consider only the mean value.

```
hi = Range[#, 1, #] &[.01];(* grid h*)
Map[(tmp = sol[#, 1];
{tmp[[1]], NIntegrate[tmp[[-1]], {y, 0, tmp[[1]]}]/tmp[[1]]}) &,hi] // ListPlot[#, AxesLabel -> {"h", "Mean[dpdx]"}] &
```

[image]

Probably this answers your question [Plot the Integration of an expression that uses the results of NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290080/plot-the-integration-of-an-expression-that-uses-the-results-of-ndsolve) too!

Hope it helps!