# Plot the Integration of an expression that uses the results of NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I want to plot the Integration of an expression that uses the results of NDSolve. But I am getting a blank window from the following code.

```
a = 0.5;
b = 2.0;
t = 0.0;
Q0 = 1.0;
alp = 0.5;
alpha = 0.5;
beta = 1.0;
k = 0.5;
(*F=Q0*Exp[-alp*t];*)
p[m_, x_, F_] := 
 Module[{mval = m, xval = x, fval = F}, 
  h = 1.0 - (a*Cos[Pi*(xval - t)]*Cos[Pi*(xval - t)]);
  eq1 = {s''[y] == (mval/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]]};
  bc1 = {s'[0] == 0, s[h] == 1};
  eq2 = {p''''[y] - (1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*s'[y] == 0};
  bc2 = {p[0] == 0, p''[0] == 0, p[h] == fval, p'[h] == 0};
  px = NDSolveValue[Join[eq1, eq2, bc1, bc2], 
    NIntegrate[(p'''[
        y] - ((1.0/k)*p''[y]) + (beta*mval*mval*s[y])), {xval, 0, 
      1}], {y, 0, h}]; px]
 
Plot[Evaluate[Table[p[m, F], {m, {1, 5, 10, 40}}]], {F, -3, 3}, 
  PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"m = ", m}], {m, {1, 5, 10, 40}}], 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"F", "\[CapitalDelta]p"}, 
  PlotRange -> All] // Quiet
```

Comment: Your function `p` takes three variables, but you are calling it with only two: `p[m,F]`

Comment: Because I have used NIntegrate for some expression over the variable x?

Comment: If a function is defined with three arguments (variables or constants) then it is undefined with only two arguments. You cannot plot an undefined function. Either provide a third argument in the function’s call or add a definition for the function when called with two arguments.

Comment: I want to integrate the expression `(p'''[y] - ((1.0/k)*p''[y]) + (beta*mval*mval*s[y])) ` over the range 0<x<1 and then want to plot the integrated value as a function of the variable F for -3<F<3. Also I need the same graph for different values of m as mentioned in my code. What should I do?

Comment: Expression you want to integrate depends on `y` as well.  Is `y` fixed or not?

Comment: In that case, we can fix `y`. Still, I am not getting the desired graphs. I have sent you an email about this. Hope you have seen the same.

Comment: @Dr.B.Mallick This question seems to be strongly related to your other question  []( https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290061/plot-the-evaluated-results-of-ndsolve) For users trying to help you this would be an important information! Why didn't you mention it?

Comment: See my  answer [Plot the evaluated results of NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290061/plot-the-evaluated-results-of-ndsolve)